# How do I stop SBT from interrupting remaining threads on clean exit?

Tags: scala, sbt

When I invoke the `runMain` task and the VM cleanly exits, it interrupts any daemon threads which already have shutdown hooks, this means these threads hooks aren't getting executed.

```
[debug] Interrupting remaining threads (should be all daemons).
[debug] Interrupting thread Thread-7
[debug]     Interrupted Thread-7
[debug] Interrupting thread MVStore background writer nio:/Users/bryan/db/example-app.mv.db
[debug]     Interrupted MVStore background writer nio:/Users/bryan/db/example-app.mv.db
[debug] Interrupting thread HikariPool-15 housekeeper
[debug]     Interrupted HikariPool-15 housekeeper
[debug] Sandboxed run complete..
[debug] Exited with code 0
```

In this case, the H2 Server is not being shutdown cleanly leaving locks on the backing store.

The effective code would be:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val props = getProps(args)
  val ds = new HikariDataSource
  try {
    ds.setDriverClassName(prop.getProperty("db.driver"))
    ds.setJdbcUrl(prop.getProperty("db.url"))
    ds.setUsername(prop.getProperty("db.user"))
    ds.setPassword(prop.getProperty("db.pass"))

    val jt = new JdbcTemplate(ds)
    jt.execute("create table if not exists TEST (id identity, name varchar)")
  } catch {
    case e: Throwable => {
      e.printStackTrace()
    }
    ds.close()
  }
```

IMHO this behaviour of SBT is a bug and it should wait for all registered shutdown hooks to complete before performing any interrupting.

Comment: I'd say it's more likely a bug in H2 Server. Using daemon threads to handle IO or resources is a bad idea, as they are supposed to be abandoned when JVM halts.

Comment: Actually daemon threads are supposed to be running before the hooks are called. It is normal for daemon threads to handle resources, as that's generally their function with them responding to shutdown hooks. [Runtime#addShutdownHook(Thread)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook-java.lang.Thread-)